# Do I have to manually rethrow an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following call hierarchy:

class A -> class B -> class C

If an exception is thrown in class C and i want to handle it in class A, do i have to manually rethrow it in class B, or does it bubble up through the call hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does automatically bubble up if you don't catch it anywhere along the way. A complete code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

void C() 
{
    throw exception();
}

void B() 
{
    C();
}

void A() 
{
    try {
        B();
    } catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what();      // Here you can access the exception thrown by C()
    }
}

int main()
{
    A();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An exception "bubbles up" the call stack until either a handler is found or `std::terminate` is called if not.

*<sub>Note: You may see different behaviour with a custom `unexpected` handler in place, in case of dynamic exception specification violations.</sub>*

Comment: Or a [dynamic exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) is violated.

Comment: @IInspectable: Which per default calls `std::unexpected` which in turn calls `std::terminate`.

Comment: No, not quite. Violating a dynamic exception specification calls [std::unexpected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected), which in turn calls the **currently installed** [std::unexpected_handler](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected_handler). The default std::unexpected_handler calls [std::terminate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate).

Comment: @IInspectable: That's what `per default` says (which i meant to refer to unexpected as well as terminate).

Comment: What you meant to write and what you did write are not the same then. My objection still holds: There is a non-zero number of possible code paths, where an exception is neither caught nor followed by a call to `std::terminate`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the way this is set up is: `class A::method()` calls `class B::method()` calls `class C::method()`,

The construction of an exception object will envoke [Stack Unwinding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw#Stack_unwinding):

> The control flow works backwards (*up the call stack*) until it reaches the start of a `try` block, at which point the parameters of all associated catch blocks are compared, in order of appearance, with the type of the exception object to find a match (see `try-catch` for details on this process). If no match is found, the control flow continues to unwind the stack until the next `try` block, and so on. If a match is found, the control flow jumps to the matching catch block.

Normally clean up is part of this "Stack Unwinding" up to the `catch`-block matching the exception object that was thrown (or a `catch(...)` which matches any exception object). But if no such `catch`-block is found [`terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is called, and the standard does *not* require that objects be cleaned up.